# What variable should I pass here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a profile model and a user has_one profile. Also, the profile is a nested resource inside the user resource. I'm creating an edit.html.erb form for the profile view. What variable should I be passing to the form in this line:

```
<%= form_for(????) do |f| %>
```

By the way, this is my edit method in the profiles controller:

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.profiles.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
<%= form_for([@user, @profile]) do |f|  %>
```

Comment: is this meant for a new User view? Because I was referring to the edit Profile view...